# Shell script to download Project Euler problems and combine to PDF

Tags: bash, web-scraping, sh, curl, pdf

[This is a script](https://github.com/jxu/project-euler-offline/tree/8efb675283234ce6221134e21699a2659cced885) I created that downloads Project Euler webpages and combines them to PDF. The script also downloads animated files.

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in $(seq -f "%03g" $1 $2); do 
    URL="https://projecteuler.net/problem=$i"
    # chromium print to PDF, wait for rendering https://stackoverflow.com/a/49789027
    chromium-browser --headless --disable-gpu --run-all-compositor-stages-before-draw --virtual-time-budget=10000 --print-to-pdf-no-header --print-to-pdf=$i.pdf $URL

    # Distill PDFs to workaround Ghostscript skipped character problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806911
    gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o ${i}_gs.pdf $i.pdf

    # download extra txt and GIF files if available, printing links to shell
    curl -s $URL | pup 'a attr{href}'  | grep '\.txt$' | tee /dev/tty | sed 's/^/https:\/\/projecteuler.net\//' | xargs -r -n1 curl -O 
    curl -s $URL | pup 'img attr{src}' | grep '\.gif$' | tee /dev/tty | sed 's/^/https:\/\/projecteuler.net\//' | xargs -r -n1 curl -O 
done

# remove non-animated GIFs
for i in *.gif; do 
    [ $(identify "$i" | wc -l) -le 1 ] && rm -v "$i"
done

# combine all PDFs using gs
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook -sOutputFile=problems.pdf *_gs.pdf
# create final zip
zip problems.zip problems.pdf *.txt *.gif
```

- Is there a way to get rid of the two nearly duplicate lines which only differ in pup and grep?
- Is it possible to write the curl lines so that an image is saved only if ImageMagick `identify` indentifies as gif, instead of cleaning up afterwards? Is this cleaner?
- I'm not very experienced writing shell scripts so let me know if there are any style issues or better ways to use sed, grep, xargs, etc.

Comment: This is tagged [tag:bash] but the shebang says `/bin/sh`. The near-duplicated lines would be easy to refactor with a process substitution but that requires the shebang to be changed to invoke `bash` instead. Please [edit] to clarify whether this is acceptable or perhaps even intended by the conflicting tags.

Comment: Either is fine for an answer. I'm not really familiar with the added features of bash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a refactoring with various fixes.

- [Generally quote shell variables.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)
- [Don't read lines with `for`.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)
- I switched the `URL` variable to lower case, in accordance with [recommended convention.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)
- This uses a temporary file for the `curl` output, and a `trap` to clean it up.
- The logic to process this file was refactored to a function `pupcurl`. I switched the regex separator in the `sed` script to `%` to reduce the need for backslashes.
- Use `./` prefix for glob expressions so as to avoid having file names which start with dashes be interpreted as (presumably invalid) options.
- `$i` in the URL is not defined outside the loop. Move the assignment inside the loop.

For the record, there is no way to run `identify` on an image without downloading it first.

```
#!/bin/sh

tmp=$(mktemp -t pdfstitcher.XXXXXXXX) || exit
trap 'rm -f "$tmp"' EXIT

pupcurl () {
    pup "$1" | grep "$2" |
    tee /dev/tty |
    sed 's%^%https://projecteuler.net/%' |
    xargs -r -n1 curl -O 
}

seq -f "%03g" "$1" "$2" |
while read -r i; do 
    url="https://projecteuler.net/problem=$i"

    chromium-browser --headless --disable-gpu \
      --run-all-compositor-stages-before-draw \
      --virtual-time-budget=10000 \
      --print-to-pdf-no-header \
      --print-to-pdf="$i.pdf" "$url"

    gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
       -o "${i}_gs.pdf" "$i.pdf"

    curl -s "$url" >"$tmp"
    pupcurl 'a attr{href}' '\.txt$' <"$tmp"
    pupcurl 'img attr{src}' '\.gif$' <"$tmp"
done

for i in ./*.gif; do 
    [ $(identify "$i" | wc -l) -le 1 ] && rm -v "$i"
done

gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
   -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook \
   -sOutputFile=problems.pdf ./*_gs.pdf
zip problems.zip problems.pdf ./*.txt ./*.gif
```

Depending on what you want to accomplish, perhaps all of this should run in a temporary directory which you remove when you're done (`mktemp -d`).

I'm not entirely happy with the `identify` call. I assume the code looks for GIF files where `identify` outputs more than one line, and removes the rest. This looks suspiciously like a [useless use of `wc`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#wc) but I'm drawing a blank when it comes to actually improving it. Perhaps it could be broken out into a separate function with some comments to explain it, or maybe use Awk to postprocess the result:

```
keep_only_animated_gifs () {
    for i in ./*.gif; do
        identify "$i" |
        awk 'NR == 2 { exit 1 }' ||
        rm -v "$i"
    done
}
```

If you are willing to change from a `sh` script to a Bash script, the temporary file (and thus also the `trap`) could be avoided with something like

```
    curl -s "$url" |
    tee >(pupcurl 'a attr{href}' '\.txt$') |
    pupcurl 'img attr{src}' '\.gif$'
```

The `>(...)` is a process substitution which is a Bash extension. Perhaps see also [Difference between sh and bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash)

The `tee /dev/tty` is slightly dubious but I left it in. If the intent is to display the output to the user as a progress message, perhaps `tee /dev/stderr` instead, though then ideally the output should have a bit of an explanation, too. (A common convention is to include the generating script's name in all diagnostic messages, so you can see which script is emitting it when you have scripts calling scripts calling scripts etc.)

Based on feedback in the comments, I removed the Bashism to `trap ... ERR` too (good catch! And insidious to run Shellckeck when clearly I didn't :-) which means this could leave temporary files behind if `curl` fails to connect, for example. Maybe add `set -e` at the top to cover that case, too; but I haven't combed over the script to check whether it's otherwise `set -e` -safe. (In particular, could `gs` fail spuriously?)

Finally, probably try http://shellcheck.net/ before asking for human assistance. It can suggest several of the changes here automatically.

Comment: ShellCheck says: [In POSIX sh, trapping ERR is undefined. \[SC3047\]](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC3047).

Comment: `identify "$i" | { read -r id1 && read -r id2;} || rm -v "$i"`

Comment: Does don't read lines with for apply mainly to arbitrary input files? because we know what seq should output

Comment: There's also the issue of needlessly having the shell collect a list into memory to loop over. Perhaps see also the `ARG_MAX` discussion on the "useless use of ..." page.

Comment: I found out later that chromium itself has some bug where about 75% of the time the page doesn't render at all. I will have to look into alternatives that can still handle rendering mathjax with js (main challenge in rendering)

Comment: or stubbornly keep trying to render over and over and hope I don't hit some race condition. but that's for another question https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=993686

Comment: As for the `tee` usage, I found out that curl has `-w` which can print the url after the transfer

Comment: Also having `url="https://projecteuler.net/problem=$i"` outside the for loop will not put in `$i` correctly in the curl command?

Comment: Thanks for noticing; updated.